# Resizing Image Data Pixel-by-Pixel using Python

Tags: python, algorithm, image, vector, scaling

### Description

Say, I have the data about an 4x4 image:

```py
IMG = (
    [ 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [ 5, 6, 7, 8],
    [ 9,10,11,12],
    [13,14,15,16]
)
```

How would I, without using those of "heavy" big-data modules, Scale it up to 6x6 or 8x8?

### Trials

I made these two attempts, (upon help from ChatGPT and Bing's GPT)

```py
def resize_image(image):
    height = len(image)
    width = len(image[0])
    new_height = height * 1.5
    new_width = width * 1.5
    new_image = [[0 for j in range(new_width)] for i in range(new_height)]
    for i in range(new_height):
        for j in range(new_width):
            x = i // 2
            y = j // 2
            new_image[i][j] = image[x][y]
    return new_image
```

It works but only for sizes that are integer-multiples of the original resolution, say I want `4x4` to `8x8` It will work fine... but not for `4x4` to `6x6`...

After more trials and **ChatGPT**, I assembled this:

```
def resize_image(image, new_height, new_width):
    height = len(image)
    width = len(image[0])
    scale_factor_x = (width - 1) / (new_width - 1)
    scale_factor_y = (height - 1) / (new_height - 1)
    new_image = [[0 for j in range(new_width)] for i in range(new_height)]
    for i in range(new_height):
        for j in range(new_width):
            x = j * scale_factor_x
            y = i * scale_factor_y
            x1 = int(x)
            y1 = int(y)
            x2 = min(x1 + 1, width - 1)
            y2 = min(y1 + 1, height - 1)
            q11 = image[y1][x1]
            q12 = image[y2][x1]
            q21 = image[y1][x2]
            q22 = image[y2][x2]
            new_image[i][j] = int(q11 * (x2 - x) * (y2 - y) + q21 * (x - x1) * (y2 - y) + q12 * (x2 - x) * (y - y1) + q22 * (x - x1) * (y - y1))
    return new_image
```

which hillariously gives me this:

```
[
  [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0],
  [3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 0],
  [5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 0],
  [8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 0],
  [10, 11, 11, 12, 13, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

What am I missing in here?

Comment: Algorithms such as the `bilinear resizing algorithm` can do that. But nothing as trivial as what you seem to belooking for. PIL [can do that for you](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize). That's a problem which we really couldn't solve well before ML models came to the party.

Comment: @Er... Actually, I want to implement the algorithm in another Language, which doesn't really have Such libraries... That's why I've asked

Comment: Then research bilinear interpolation and write your own.

Answer (score 0):

You will find your answer here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-bicubic-interpolation-for-resizing-image/

In this example, the author resizes the image by using bicubic interpolation using numpy and for loops.

I will summarize the needed steps here:

1. Add padding to your input image
2. Define the kernel function that will approximate the missing pixel values "it can be nearest neighbor, bilinear, bicubic, etc. "
3. Construct an empty image with the new dimensions
4. start filling the empty image with the input image and the kernel

I think if the dimensions are small enough like from 4x4 to 6x6 and 8x8, you can just use any padding strategy like reflect or symmetric etc. And the result of the padding will be your scaled image.

Comment: @Moustada_Hegazy , actually, I, as mentioned, wanted to do this without using any big-data modules... I hope this confusion got cleared..

Comment: You can implement the same code in the link without any big-data modules, if you opened it you will see that the open_cv is there just to read the image and numpy is used for indexing, you can easily index your array in any other way, and as i clarified you can use the padding strategy to scale your image if the dimension is 6x6 as you mentioned.

Comment: Oh, okay ... Thanks... Back then i wasn't with my "system", soi just saw modules and commented.... Sorry 'bout that